# Alternative authentication if certificate authentication fails (IIS,C#,ASP.NET MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, authentication, iis-7.5

Our project(web application `C# ASP.NET MVC3`) is hosted on `IIS 7.5` and we use certificate authentication. So we have SSL-require configured `IIS`.

Now we have a business task to allow some users to use our system. And there is no way to provide client certificates for them. In that case we need to use some additional authentication model (user-password or ntdomain based).

I don't know how to realize such model:

1. User gets on our project url;
2. If he has valid client certificate - we let him iteract with our application;
3. If he hasn't cert we show him a login form with "user-password";

If we use SSL-required configured `IIS` users would not be able to iteract with application without valid certificate at all right? And how to authenticate with certificate if `IIS` is configured with SSL-Accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not so large as i thought before. IIS provides a check box to require certificate even if combobox(in SSL options of web application) is set to Accept instead of require. In that case IIS tries to get certificate at first. And if there is no cert it lets the user to iteract with application. And we can make custom authentication on that level.

With MVC (v.3+) there is nice way to use IAuthorizationFilter in that case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can configure two sites on your IIS? One with SSL and another without it? Your url will point to the SSL enabled site, and when a user without a valid certificate arrives you use some backup code to send him to the SSL free site?

Just guessing actually... I think this probably deserves a more meditated answer...

Comment: Hello. The problem was not so large as i thought before. IIS provides a check box to require certificate even if combobox(in SSL options of web application) is set to Accept instead of require. In that case IIS tries to get certificate at first. And if there is no cert it lets the user to iteract with application. And we can make custom authentication on that level.

Comment: Quite intheresting, I'll note that up

Comment: With MVC (v.3+) there is nice way to use IAuthorizationFilter in that case.